# .Net serialization outputting extra > at end of xml document sometimes

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have a simple `ObjectToSerialize settings` passed as an argument into a method called PersistSettings (for reference ObjectToSerialize has only one property - a dateTime property)

In that, PersistSettings method, I have code to serialize the ObjectToSerialize object as follows

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObjectToSerialize));
using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(filePath))
{
     serializer.Serialize(stream, settings);
}
```

Every now and again, the xml that is persisted is invalid. It is always invalid in the same way - an extra > at the end of the document. So I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ObjectToSerialize xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Item>Important piece of data</Item>
</ObjectToSerialize>>
```

When I then try and read the xml, I get an InvalidOperationException (as expected). Fortunately, the data stored in the settings can be regenerated if necessary so I am able to delete the file and save it again (but not before it saves me a copy so that I can try and work out what the problem is)

The issue doesn't seem to be tied in to any other errors or issues that are being captured or logged.

Anyone got any ideas? Or even ever seen this before?

Comment: Maybe deleting the outputfile before serializing will fix your problem.

Comment: Are you writing out to a file?  If so you may need to delete it first or use FileMode.Create so that a new file is created each time

Comment: I don't think you understand what `OpenWrite` does. [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653132/file-openwrite-appends-instead-of-wiping-contents)

Comment: Thanks wonko79 and daz-fuller - I'll give that a go. Good spot :-)